# Swing blinking component to indicate 'Busy'

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing a swing GUI, in which I constantly need to inform the user about whether a process is busy or not. I plan to do this by having a little radiobutton-sized indicator which either blinks red, or is set to green.

Which swing component would be the most elegant to use to achieve this?

Also, are there any examples of alternative slick and modern looking 'busy' indicators which you can provide?

Comment: little radiobutton-sized indicator which either blinks red, == for me Jlabel with two Icons, blink from Swing Timer

Comment: `ColorIcon`, used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), should work.